# How to get Microsoft Access to only open in design mode with shift key

Tags: ms-access

I have an Microsoft Access 2010 database that is suddenly opening in design mode- so it's showing the Create, External Data, and Database Tools options in the ribbon and I can see all the Tables, Queries, etc- without me pressing down the shift key when I open it. Does anyone know of a setting that allows this? I don't want it like this- I want it so that if the user double clicks to open the file, they should see the display form that is set in the Options and not have all the developer options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get through the guy's accent, [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=be1JPnQr8v8) is actually pretty solid and will help you lock down everything.

If you want to get a network username, try this:

Put this code in the declarations on a new module:

```
Private Declare Function apiGetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias _
    "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
```

Then, add this function to that module to get a username:

```
Public Function GetNetworkUserName() As String
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
    'Purpose:   Returns the network login name
    'Return:    The name, or "{Unknown}" on error.
    'Note:      Safer than testing Environ().
    Dim lngLen As Long
    Dim lngX As Long
    Dim strUserName As String

    strUserName = String$(254, 0&)
    lngLen = 255&
    lngX = apiGetUserName(strUserName, lngLen)
    If (lngX > 0&) Then
        strUserName = Left$(strUserName, lngLen - 1&)
    End If

    If strUserName <> vbNullString Then
        GetNetworkUserName = strUserName
    Else
        GetNetworkUserName = "{unknown}"
    End If

Exit_Handler:
    Exit Function

Err_Handler:
    Call LogError(Err.Number, Err.Description, conMod & ".fOSUserName")
    Resume Exit_Handler
End Function
```

Then, on a form (maybe your main form or opening form), you can get the username by putting this in somewhere in the OnLoad event:

```
UName = UCase(GetNetworkUserName())
```

You can then write that variable name and a timestamp to an "Auditing" table to keep track of who is in the database and when they logged on.

Comment: I found what I was looking for around 2:23- in Options, under "Ribbon and Toolbar Options", I needed to uncheck "Allow Full Menus." Now if only I knew who was messing around in my database...

Comment: If it's on an Intranet then you can capture the users' LAN IDs when they open the DB.  That won't tell you who's editing it, but it'll at least let you narrow it down.  Theoretically you could probably capture any usage of the F10 key and store the current user's LAN, and then you'd know exactly who it was, but I've never done that myself so I'm not positive it would work.

Comment: Depending on your needs you can also lock down most of these features so it becomes very difficult for anyone to make changes like this in the future.  Though it can be fairly time consuming but if you need it the option is there.

Comment: The end users are opening it through Citrix (of which I am not familiar), which links to the file on a network share. I would love to know the IDs of who is opening it, though- would that still be possible, is that done through Access or something else?

Comment: @Kelly - See my edit above for how you can track who uses the DB.  It works for me, I'm not 100% positive it works over citrix but it might.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyBones, got that code to work to get the username but not over Citrix (haven't had the chance to try it, I'm working remotely on this)

Comment: @Kelly - I think it's because Citrix is logged into the WAN as itself and so it acts as a shell.  Everyone who logs in just picks up the Citrix server's ID.  You might want to post a specific new question about obtaining a user's LAN ID while connecting through Citrix, using VBA.  A quick Google gave me nothing, but I'm sure someone out there has done it before.  Good luck!